# Angular Reactive Forms - .disable() in custom validation causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm learning and using reactive forms with Angular 11. I've created a custom validator that makes two FormControls in the same FormGroup mutually exclusive.
e.g. Building Name OR Building Number.
Inside the custom validator I am disabling a FormControl if the other one has any input. This is emitting an event that reevaluates the validation, causing an infinite loop.
I've tried using control1.enable({ **emitEvent: false** }) but it makes no difference.

#### Mutually Exclusive using Custom Validator

```
export function mutuallyExl(ctrl1: string, ctrl2: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    let control1 = c.get(ctrl1);
    let control2 = c.get(ctrl2);
    if (!control1.value && !control2.value) {
      control1.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      control2.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      return null;
    } else if (control1.value && control2.value) {
      control1.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      control2.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      return { exclusive: true };
    } else if (control1.value) {
      control2.disable({ emitEvent: false });
      return null;
    } else {
      control1.disable({ emitEvent: false });
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

I've already solved this problem by using **valueChanges.subscribe**, but I would like to keep the functionality contained within a custom validator if possible.

#### Mutually Exclusive using valueChanges

```
    const buildingNumber = this.formRoot.get('buildingNumber');
    const buildingName = this.formRoot.get('buildingName');
    buildingNumber.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
      if (newValue) {
        buildingName.disable({ emitEvent: false });
      } else {
        buildingName.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      }
    });
    buildingName.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
      if (newValue) {
        buildingNumber.disable({ emitEvent: false });
      } else {
        buildingNumber.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      }
    });
```

Comment: A validator should be a pure function. IMO the subscribe to valueChanges approach is more correct than putting side effects in the validator.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll take your word for it as I'm just learning reactive forms.